# Use graphic.attr to chaneg the highchart pie color, however color turn back when hover

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I create a pie chart and want to grey out all other color but leave the color I clicked. At first I used `chart.series[i].color = 'rgb(100,100,100)'` to change the color, but it did not work. Finally I used `chart.series[i].graphic.attr({ fill: 'rgb(100,100,100)' })` and this time it works. However, when I hover in the area, the grey area change back to its original color, probably the mousein/out event still keeps its original color, so everytime I hover it grasp the old color to display. Is there any better way to change the color of pie and after change the color stays till next click event? I also tried update/redraw but it is wired and like some kind of delay action.

The code is here [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u6v5Ln1x/4/)

What I want is every time when select colored part in pie chart, other is greyout, and do not change color until I select it or I reselect the color one to reset the overall graph.
However, now it grey out, but when I hover, it change the color back.

Comment: need more info - please post an example demonstrating your problem. all the relevant code needs to be included.

Comment: Add demo now, when hover over grey one, it changes color back. How to prevent it?

Comment: `attr()` will change only SVG color, but in options it will remain default option. `update()` doesn't work with color because is broken in 4.1.9, but it's been fixed in prerelease version (candidate for 4.1.10), see: http://jsfiddle.net/u6v5Ln1x/6/